# Default back button not showing after pushing new screen

Tags: dart, flutter

I had pushed a new Screen from my main screen and it had navigated smoothly and also showed the back button however now that I run the button, the default button is not showing in my code.

The only change that I made was that I changed the route in my main file from `taskScreen()` to `task()`.
But this was essential as i wanted to make some more routes from my second screen and so it had to return a `Material App`. 
How can i get the default back button back?

My code:

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: DefaultTabController(length: 2,child: MyHomePage(title: '')),
      routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
       "/TaskScreen": (BuildContext context) => new task(), //CHANGED HERE 
      },
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){

   return Scaffold(

     appBar: AppBar(
    ..
     ),
     body: ...
 }
}
```

My second screen

```
class task extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Task',
        home: new taskScreen(),
        routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
          "/Completed": (BuildContext context) => new Completed()
        }
    );
  }
}

class taskScreen extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
  taskState createState() => new taskState();
}

class taskState extends State<taskScreen> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

  Column taskScreen = Column (...)

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Task Screen')),
      body: taskScreen,
    );
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Class name must to start with uppercase character. You have wrong structure, MaterialApp must to be only one time.
https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour

Comment: Thankyou! I will fix my classNames and remove the other Material App!

Answer (score 2):

For me it happened when I added a draw to all my various AppBars ... quick googling provided a solution which worked for me:
I added to the AppBar the following which let flutter take a conscious decision whether there is or is not what to go back to ...

```
automaticallyImplyLeading: true,
```

Then I added defined how the "leading" should look like (also to the appbar):

```
leading: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
          onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, false),
        ),
```

Making a long story short: Adding the following to the respective AppBar did the work:

```
        leading: IconButton(
      icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
      onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, false),
    ),
```

Answer (score -1):

Remove the second routes MaterialApp and replace it with an AppBar